# How is base fee calculated?

Tags: fee

How is base fee calculated?

[image]

---

**My understanding is that `WeightToFee` is just a transformation equation(`Weight -> Balance`).**
**But what is this `x`?**

So the **final transaction fee** is this?:

```bash
base_fee = (-/+)coeff_integer * x^(degree) + coeff_frac * x^(degree);
inclusion_fee = base_fee + length_fee + [targeted_fee_adjustment * weight_fee];
total_fee = inclusion_fee + tip;
```

https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/weights/struct.WeightToFeeCoefficient.html

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base fee represents the fee of any extrinsic with a certain extrinsic class, not yet including the specific logic of that extrinsic. That is to say, that there is some overhead fee required for any extrinsic, even one that executes no logic, and the base fee represents that.

The documented definition is:

> *base fee*: This is the minimum amount a user pays for a transaction. It is declared as a base *weight* in the runtime and converted to a fee using `WeightToFee`.

Weight is has a standard value across all chains representing pico-seconds. For example, 1 seconds of weight would be `1_000_000_000_000`.

Since Weight has a standard representation, but all blockchains can have different representations of currencies, we need a function like `WeightToFee` to allow a blockchain developer to convert between the standard weight value to a representation of the blockchian currency.

For example:

Imagine I have two chains which represent a USD stable coin, however, one uses 12 decimals, and the other uses 9 decimals.

So to represent $1, you would have:

```
chain a: 1_000_000_000_000 UNITS
chain b: 1_000_000_000 UNITS
```

Where `UNITS` is the lowest denomination of that currency.

Now imagine you want to have both chains charge $1, for 1 second of computation on the network.

Chain a would define a `WeightToFee` function which is simply the identity, since these two values match 1:1.

```rust
fn weight_to_fee(weight: u64) -> Balance {
    weight.into()
}
```

However, chain b would need to adjust the weight value to turn it into the appropriate fee since they only use 9 decimals:

```rust
fn weight_to_fee(weight: u64) -> Balance {
    (weight / 1000).into()
}
```

Within the transaction payment pallet, `WeightToFee` is a trait that can be defined by the runtime developer, and can even have more complex logic. For example, imagine charging different amounts of fees at different tiers:

```rust
fn weight_to_fee(weight: u64) -> Balance {
    if weight > THRESHOLD_1 {
         (weight * FEE_MULTIPLIER_1).into()
    } else if (weight > THRESHOLD_2)
         (weight * FEE_MULTIPLIER_2).into()
    } else if ...
}
```

So to answer your question, there is no concrete way that these things are calculated for all Substrate chains. If you are asking about a specific chain like Polkadot, you can look at the implementation of the `WeightToFee` trait:

```rust
    /// Handles converting a weight scalar to a fee value, based on the scale and granularity of the
    /// node's balance type.
    ///
    /// This should typically create a mapping between the following ranges:
    ///   - [0, `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT`]
    ///   - [Balance::min, Balance::max]
    ///
    /// Yet, it can be used for any other sort of change to weight-fee. Some examples being:
    ///   - Setting it to `0` will essentially disable the weight fee.
    ///   - Setting it to `1` will cause the literal `#[weight = x]` values to be charged.
    pub struct WeightToFee;
    impl WeightToFeePolynomial for WeightToFee {
        type Balance = Balance;
        fn polynomial() -> WeightToFeeCoefficients<Self::Balance> {
            // in Polkadot, extrinsic base weight (smallest non-zero weight) is mapped to 1/10 CENT:
            let p = super::currency::CENTS;
            let q = 10 * Balance::from(ExtrinsicBaseWeight::get());
            smallvec![WeightToFeeCoefficient {
                degree: 1,
                negative: false,
                coeff_frac: Perbill::from_rational(p % q, q),
                coeff_integer: p / q,
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I take it this way. **base_fee = WeightToFee(ExtrinsicBaseWeight);**

**weight_fee = WeightToFee(weight);**

Comment: I am clear about the function of `WeightToFee`, but I am not clear about the independent variable of WeightToFee.

Comment: My understanding is that base fee is actually `WeightToFee(ExtrinsicBaseWeight);`.

Comment: And `weight fee` is `WeightToFee(weight)`.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me, or what problem you are running into, or what problem you are trying to solve. Please spend the time to clarify your question so that we can more specifically help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem, I now have a new problem, I will raise a new problem.

Comment: If this answers your question, please do mark it as answered. Thanks.